# C# Winforms SQLAuthentication fails when running exe from share, works running locally

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a Windows Form app that a connects to a SQL Server database using a connection string in the following format:

```
ConnectionString='Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=UserName;Password
```

When the user double clicks on the exe in a folder on his desktop, he is able to successfully connect to the database. When we copy the binary folder to a share drive and he double clicks on it, the program throws and error message when it attempts to connect to the database  (on the SqlConnection.Open() command).

This used to work for him, but recently he was remove from a global group that provided write access to the share.  I captured the SQL Authentication CONNECTION STRING in each case, when it worked and when it failed. It is identical. Since I know that it is failing exactly on the OpenConnection statement (as opposed to, say, attempting to write to a log file), I don't see why not having write access to the share would matter.

One question. Is the word "Data Source=" in the connection string below identical to "Server="?

```
ConnectionString='Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=UserName;Password
```

Or does this the "DataSource" usage expect a ODBC/OLE DSN to be created in the Control Panel? I would assume that it is synonymous with Server since I would expect the user NOT to have the DSN on his machine (where the app ran successfully) and I would expect that when running from the share location that the presence of a DSN on the share server would NOT even be accessible (I'm grasping at straws here.)

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No process is on the other end of the pipe
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(SNIHandle handle, SNIPacket packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SendPreLoginHandshake(Byte[] instanceName, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

**Update**

I changed the connection string to use an IP address

```
   ConnectionString='Server=IPADDRESS;Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=UserName;Password
```

based on what I read here:

[Name resolution in connection string fails from network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795432/name-resolution-in-connection-string-fails-from-network-share)

Same result.

Comment: The error says that it's trying to connect using named pipes. Are those enabled, on the server side, for remote hosts?

Comment: I'm not sure. It may take me a while to get the answer from someone with access. However, why would it matter depending on whether we are running from a share or not? I am now wondering whether using an IP address in place of a server name would matter. Could the server resolution somehow be failing. I just saw this but haven't digested it yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795432/name-resolution-in-connection-string-fails-from-network-share

Comment: Does the share name and dir to the executable have any special characters or suspect naming conventions.   Also are you executing   \\MySrv\MyShare\MyDir\MyExe.exe   or  H:\MyShare\MyDir\MyExe.exe     You might try using a shortcut that sets the current directory to that network dir and see if that makes a difference.  It might give you a clue.

Comment: Yes, one of the folders has a space in it. I'll remove it. He accesses the share in Windows Explorer as a UNC path and double clicks on it. I'll try creating a shortcut in the folder that sets the current folder. Not too sure why this would matter though, it seems like the only thing that would matter is teh connection string

Answer (score 0):

I think you are publishing the project you have to add file where your connection string is stored. According to your connection string you have to use provider name in it. When publishing or making exe select include file in your project.

Comment: In both cases, when it works and when it does not work, I;ve captured the connection string and compared, They are identical. The code was "deployed" by doing a folder copy. Thanks, but the answer sounds off target

Comment: the reason behind this only when you are missing files when deployment. The local code always work and we had to add dlls , files in the project

Comment: No files are missing.